# Running a .cmd file through Java code

Tags: java

I am trying to run a .cmd program from Java. Doesn't run.
I'm using `Runtime.exec` as advised in some other posts.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
  Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

  String path = "E:/Marvin/Marvin_Cleanup.CMD";

  try {
    runtime.exec(path);
  } catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
  }         
}
```

Comment: So what does it do?  Throw the exception?  You might try catching the stderr/stdout from the process and seeing if there's useful info there.

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612921/running-a-exe-file-using-java

Comment: Well, is it an `.exe` file or a `.cmd` file?

Comment: ohh sorry its a .CMD. But shouldn't it still work?

Comment: what's in the .cmd file?

Comment: Here it is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275141/running-a-bat-cmd-file-from-java

Comment: Catch Throwable instead of Exception. You might get an error and not exception.

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with windows executeables but using the process builder combined with that url should work fine.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

If you call further batches from your batch file you might need to use **cmd /c** prefix. https://superuser.com/questions/712279/commands-run-in-a-batch-file-only-when-writing-cmd-c-before

```
String path = "cmd /c E:/Marvin/Marvin_Cleanup.CMD";
```